# Automatically truncate values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am receiving an error because my stored procedure is trying to insert a value with 12 decimals into field that only allows 6 decimal places. I realize that I can round the value before trying to enter it into the table. However, the stored procedure has hundreds of calculations and I'm trying to avoid going through and rounding every single instance.

Similar to how a SQL table can ignore duplicates without throwing an error, can a table automatically truncate decimals without throwing an error?

EDIT: As explained by Jeroen Mostert in the comments, the error was related to the number not fitting into the overall amount of allowed decimal characters rather than the decimal points themselves. For instance, my `decimal(18,6)` was not unhappy about 10 decimal places, but rather the number having more than 18 characters.

Rather than dangerously ignoring arithmetic errors I wrote a script to avoid getting bad data into the procedure before it even tried to run so that these overly large values would not throw an error. The ideal solution would be to use a try catch (or something to that capacity) but unfortunately that was not an option in this lengthy, long-established procedure.

Comment: why would you need to round every place? Can't you just round prior to the insert?

Comment: "Similar to how a SQL table can ignore duplicates without throwing an error" Really? How is that done? I've never heard of this.

Comment: You have to be more precise about what you mean with "12 decimals". SQL Server *already* rounds implicitly: `DECLARE @T TABLE(d DECIMAL(5,3)); INSERT @T VALUES (1.123456789)` will store `1.123`. However, attempting to store a value that simply will not fit in the significant digits (like `1234.1`) will produce an error that cannot be automatically recovered from, because the server can't know how you'd like to "fix" that issue.

Comment: @ZoharPeled a table without a primary key can ignore duplicates without throwing an error.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: `IGNORE_DUP_KEY`, it's an index option.

Comment: What exactly is the error? Are you sure it is caused by trailing decimal places instead of the portion _before_ decimal?

Comment: @TabAlleman of course if there is no unique index any table will ignore duplicates....

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks, Didn't know that.

Comment: @JeroenMostert is right. The error is "Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric." I confirmed this is related to the number being too large rather than there being too many decimal places. Is there a protocol to avoid this?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean "However, the stored procedure has hundreds of calculations and I'm trying to avoid going through and rounding every single instance."

Comment: What is the datatype of column? Are you sure the calculations are not creating a value that cannot be fit on the left side of decimal?

Comment: You can do `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF; SET ARITHABORT OFF; SET ARITHIGNORE ON;`. Now overflow will be converted to `NULL` instead. The fact that you have to tweak *three* settings from their usual defaults should be a sign that this should not be done lightly! Things like computed columns will cease to work under these settings, for example. The alternative is to tweak your calculations to see what should be done when they overflow (recommended) or wrap things in `TRY .. CATCH` to explicitly recover in some appropriate way.

Comment: @SalmanA That's what's happening. It is decimal(18,6) and the value is larger than 18 characters.

Comment: @cbrawl Yeah, I read the question before commenting. I don't see how hundreds of calculations has anything to do with an insert. Are you doing hundreds of separate inserts/updates in code? All of your calculations could have larger precision in memory/temp table and be truncated just prior to the insert.

Comment: Oh, and obviously (can't believe I forgot to mention it) if you identify the point at which the overflowed value is finally stored in the database (doing the calculations with higher precision in the meantime) you can use `TRY_CAST` / `TRY_CONVERT` and handle the resulting `NULL` as appropriate. This should certainly be preferred to tweaking `ARITHIGNORE`, which is really only necessary if you can't identify the point of overflow.

Comment: @cbrawl so? Problem solved? You obviously don't want to hide those errors under the carpet.

Comment: @cbrawl You can use `TRY_CAST` though if you _really_ have to.